# Combine two related line graphs

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

If I have this data

| Product 1 | Product 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3.88% | 5.71% |
| 0.70% | 4.58% |
| 0.38% | 4.64% |
| 1.41% | 1.62% |
|  | 5.24% |
|  | 1.32% |
|  | 1.15% |
|  | 6.47% |

where the percentages (Y-axes values) are a certain metric of the prodcut and are captured over the versions of each product (X-axes values). Now I want to plot both these data points from each product in the *same* graph in Powerpoint. Using the data set in the current form, this is the graph obtained

[image]

As is evident, the `Product 1`'s line graph seems to *abruptly* end and almost gives a sense of truncation. Is there a way I can somehow *space* out `Product 1`'s data so that the representation looks saner? Or better still, is there some other mode of representation that I should be chosing to represent this dataset?

Note: The X-axis values aren't really relevant here since they are the versions of each product, which obviously would be different, and aren't related per se.

Comment: @harrymc I was actually trying to get in a chart in PowerPoint but since editing the chart uses Excel anyway, I've edited the tag.

Comment: You might need to modify the values to move one a little bit up and the other down.

Answer (score 2):

> > Note: The X-axis values aren't really relevant here since they are the versions of each product, which obviously would be different, and aren't related per se.

Would you mind using Scatters to show the trend line of products?

Based on your example, I added 2 columns for different products as shown in the image. These two columns of data are related to the X-axis.

[image]

Then you can insert Scatters Chart.

[image]